# Django custom manager and queryset narrowed result

Tags: django

I want to be able to do something like this in my template:

```
request.user.notifications.unseen
```

And show the user all unseen notifications he has.

So far, based on a few posts I found here, I was able to develop this:

```
class NotificationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def unseen(self):
        return self.filter(is_read=False)


class NotificationManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_query_set(self):
        return NotificationQuerySet(self.model)

    def unseen(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get_query_set().unseen(*args, **kwargs)
```

It works fine, but it shows all 'unseen' notifications from all users.

What I thought is that by specifying the object relation, such as `user.notifications`, an argument would be passed to the function narrowing the results to the user requesting it.

So, how do I narrow the results by one user and not all of them?

## Edit

**Models.py**

```
class UserNotification(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='notifications')
    advertisement = models.ForeignKey(Advertisement)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, default=timezone.now)
    notification_type = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=NOTIFICATION_TYPE)
    is_read = models.BooleanField()

    objects = NotificationManager()
```

Comment: can you show your notification and user model?

Comment: @AhmedHosny I just did.

Comment: I think rather than having a manger and queryset, It will be better to make like this: `objects = NotificationQuerySet.as_manager()`

Comment: @AhmedHosny I didn't want to, but I will have to use a `context_processor` variable to do that. It will work as I want.

Comment: so why not filtering it in the manager itself like: `self.get_query_set().filter(is_read=False)` and remove `get_query_set`  overriding ?

Comment: Instead of calling `user.notifications`, try `user.notification_set`. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference

Answer (score 1):

```
class NotificationManager(models.Manager):

   def unseen(self,user):
      queryset = super(NotificationManager,self).get_queryset()
      queryset = queryset.filter(user=user,is_read=False)
      return queryset

class UserNotifications(models.Model):

    ... same fields ...
    objects = NotificationManager()
```

In your view:

```
queryset = UserNotifications.objects.unseen(self.request.user)
```

You get a queryset which you can further filter, use all(), get() etc, like any other queryset. Add args, kwargs and more methods to this manager, while the generic objects manager doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to perform this query in my template, not in my view.

Comment: So use this manager from the user side, if you have a user foreign key to notifications then you can access notifications manager with user.notification_set (or other field provided in related_name)

Comment: Seems that django uses only the default objects manager in relational queries. So to use it from the user side you'll have to replace the objects manager (edited the answer)

Comment: The problem is that if I do it, I will lose the standard manager, won't I?

Comment: No, you subclass the manager. The unseen method does not replace any existing method (all, get, filter etc)